# How is message exchange implemented in IBM MQ: push or pull?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ibm-mq

I'd like to understand what is the implementation of the JMS drivers for WebSphere MQ. I'm not interested in the JMS sync/async methods directly but rather in their implementation.

If an application is deployed on a J2EE server and performs asynchronous calls (by implementing onMessage()), does the J2EE server still pull to check for the availability of a message or does MQ actively call back the client (J2EE server) through the opened socket to notify the presence of the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what version of IBM MQ you are using.

Prior to MQ V7, the JMS layer would poll the queue manager for a message - essentially pull.

After MQ V7, the queue manager natively understands and implements asynchronous get where it will notify the getter of a message so it no longer has to poll.

**Further Reading**

- [What is new in WebSphere MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm35120_.htm) - about half-way down the page.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Are there any links to the corresponding sections in documentation?

Comment: Hi @PavelVasilev - I have updated my answer with a link which I hope helps.